# Compatibility between UIImagePNGRepresentation and ImageCreateFromString (Objective C and PHP)

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, jpeg

I use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to covert `UIImage` to `NSData`.
then I use Kiichi Takeuchi's Base64 library in Objective C to compress the `NSData` to `NSString`.

The code on the server (written in PHP) uses base64_decode to decode the string, and then `ImageCreateFromString`. The latter method raises an error.

Anything i am doing wrong?

- I NSLoged the output of the base64 function and tried to decode it in python and save it to a PNG file, and the file was OK
- I also tried UIImageJPEGRepresentation, same problem..

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You said “The latter method raises an error.”  That is not very much information.  If you want help with your problem, you need to provide details.  Copy the error, edit your post, and paste in the error.

Comment: The image data is probably fine. Something's wrong with your base 64 encode/decode (or on the PHP side, which I'm not familiar with). The UIImage functions produce reliably good output.

Comment: The error the server is having is not visible to me since the error I get is written by the developer of the server - it's a costume error, I can only tell where in the process it is happening.

Comment: Without details on the error or any code snippets, it's quite impossible to answer this question.